# how to integrate Signature verification for Razorpay payment gateway here in my next js project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, razorpay

This code works fine but I want to add signature verification here

```
import crypto from 'crypto'
import prisma from '@/utils/connect'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export const POST = async (req) => {
  try {
    const body = await req.json()
    const { event, payload } = body

    const a = req.headers
    console.log(a)
    const signature = req.headers['x-razorpay-signature']
    console.log(signature)

    // The signature header is present, proceed with signature validation
    const generatedSignature = crypto
      .createHmac('sha256', 'oBtdfiQn3POvk0BtxYCUC6FY')
      .update(payload.payment.entity.order_id + '|' + payload.payment.entity.id)
      .digest('hex')

    console.log(generatedSignature)

    if (signature === generatedSignature) {
      console.log('Request is legit')
    } else {
      console.log('Wrong Signature!')
    }

    switch (event) {
      case 'payment.authorized':
        break
      case 'payment.captured':
        const donationId = payload.payment.entity.notes.donationId

        if (donationId) {
          await prisma.donation.update({
            where: { id: donationId },
            data: { status: 'Success' }
          })
        } else {
          console.error('Invalid or missing donationId from Razorpay webhook payload')
          return new NextResponse('Invalid or missing donationId', {
            status: 400
          })
        }
        break
      default:
        // Handle other events if needed
        console.log('Unhandled Event:', event)
    }

    return new NextResponse('Webhook Received', { status: 200 })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error processing webhook:', error)
    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Something went wrong!' }, { status: 500 }))
  }
}
```

iam not getting x-razorpay-signature in headers, what wrong iam doing here ? Can someone share me their updated code for razorpay payment gateway. My trasaction is going smooth , it generates all razorpay_payment_id, razorpay_order_id, razorpay_signature, but only in console, how to get that in my current code ?